# C++ AMP is slow

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, gpgpu, c++-amp

I have following code in C++:

```
float Neuron::feedForward(std::vector<Neuron>& previousLayer){
float sum=0.0f;
for(int i=0;i<(int)previousLayer.size();i+=1){
    sum+=previousLayer[i].getOutput()*weigths[i];
}
output=Neuron::transferFunction(sum);
return output;

};
```

That i converted to this:

```
float Neuron::feedForward(std::vector<Neuron>& previousLayer){
float sum=0.0f;
extent<1> e((int)previousLayer.size());

std::vector<float> ops(previousLayer.size());
for (int i = 0; i<(int)previousLayer.size(); i += 1) {
    ops[i] = previousLayer[i].getOutput();
}

array_view<const float, 1>_outputs(e, ops);
array_view<const float, 1>_weigths(e, weigths);
array_view<float> _sum(e);
_sum.discard_data();


parallel_for_each(e, [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp) {
    _sum[idx] = _outputs[idx] * _weigths[idx];

});

for (int i = 0; i < e[0]; i += 1) {
    sum += _sum[i];
}

output=Neuron::transferFunction(sum);
return output;
```

};

Now the program runs the code extremely slow. Not just few milliseconds slower, but actual seconds slower.

I also tried to have the sum inside the AMP code (only changes):

```
array_view<float> _sum(1);
_sum.discard_data();

...

parallel_for_each(e, [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp) {
_sum[0] += _outputs[idx] * _weigths[idx];
```

});

```
...

/*for (int i = 0; i < e[0]; i += 1) {
sum += _sum[i];
 }
 */

output=Neuron::transferFunction(_sum[0]);
```

But in the end, the code is just that: So slow, that I'd be faster with a hand calculator. Now the question is: Why? I thought that if I have a neuron with 2000 weigths, it'd be great to have GPU calculate everything. Am I missing something, or do I have to learn OpenCL or CUDA?

PS. The slownes is really bad. Like it takes more than 100 000 times longer (in the same time I can calculate 20 000 neural networks ten times, i can calculate 2 exactly the same networks once using AMP).

Comment: You could try adding a synchronize call on e after the parallel_for_each block. According to C++ AMP tutorial here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882446.aspx, the synchronization should be performed automatically. But, if you don't call synchronize() explicitly, you will lose exceptions, so maybe this will turn something up?

Comment: I suspect you don't know how to use AMP well.  It appears you are insisting to accumulate a sum of products into a scalar _sum[0]. If I understand this right, you are forcing the generated code to send all the products to particular processor that holds sum[0] ("lots of communication"), and/or forcing all updates to that sum to execute a global lock ("lots of lock interference").  Neither of these are efficient.  I think you would do well to spend some time reading about data parallel programming, techniques and pitfalls, and then then use that knowledge to revise your program for AMP.

Comment: I don't know if I can call synchronize on e, but on _sum there are no std::exception triggered. Could it be possible, that because I run on laptop, the GPU is somehow in sleepmode, and AMP falls back on cpu? Although My CPU useage is ~10%, which means one of the threads on my computer is running 90% of its capabilities.

Comment: To Ira Baxter: What about when I try to get the code to use _sum[idx]? Should that be any different, as each GPU core has their own _sum to put their value to?

Comment: I tested choosing an accelerator manually. Still no difference. Also on a different machine, and different version of visual studio (originally 2015 community, now 2012 ultimate). So the problem has to be in the code.

I also timed the whole thing using a rather large layer of calculations: While GPU could do one of these layers in around 600-700ms, CPU was done in 0-1ms.

Answer (score 1):

Your code using `sum[0]` will almost certainly give incorrect results as many threads are updating `sum[0]` concurrently.

The naive implementation should work but is very inefficient because there is a significant copy overhead for moving data to and from the GPU and you are doing very little compute.

However, for it to be as slow as you say it seems likely that you are running on the WARP accelerator on the CPU. You can use the following code to see what accelerators are available.

https://ampbook.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/ShowAmpDevices/ShowAmpDevices.cpp

What you are doing here is a reduction. There are many articles on how to do this efficiently on a GPU. You can find C++AMP code showing several different implementations here:

[C++ AMP: Accelerated Massive Parallelism with Microsoft Visual C++](https://ampbook.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/CaseStudies/Reduction/Reduction.sln) on CodePlex.

They are fully explained in the book that goes with the code.

Comment: The _sum[0] was one of the tests, I also tried _sum[idx]. I know this is not optimal code yet, but it is a simple block for me to learn AMP (later on I plan on just moving data to the GPU, and calculating everything there, but now i use this to learn the process).

I added code to choose GPU manually, GeForce 570. I also tried the code from your link, and my device says: Dedicated memory: 1.2mb, has display=true, is_debug and is_emulated are both false, and it supports limited and double precision. I'm going to try CUDA, in case there is some problem with my AMP.